# Is there a way to display PNG/SVG in before: content TailwindCSS?

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

Is there a way to display PNG/SVG in before: content TailwindCSS?

component

```
<li className={`${liClassname} z-[4] before:content-profile`}>
    <a className={aClassname}>Profile</a>
</li>
```

tailwind.config.js

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      content: {
        profile: 'url("/src/app/assets/icons/profile.svg")',
      }
    },
}
```

Want to display PNG or SVG in before: content, Thanks in advance